# Ecto: Dynamic order_by with count query on virtual field

Tags: elixir, ecto

I want to build a query with dynamic order by handling.
The basic sorting example id + name (see below) works fine. The sort variable is inserted in query.

```
favorites_count_query = from(f in Favorite,
  select: %{wallpaper_id: f.wallpaper_id, count: count(f.user_id)},
  group_by: f.wallpaper_id)

...

sort = [asc: :id, asc: :name] # comes from request

from(w in Wallpaper,
  left_join: f in subquery(favorites_count_query), on: f.wallpaper_id == w.id,
  left_join: d in subquery(downloads_count_query), on: d.wallpaper_id == w.id,
  select: w,
  select_merge: %{favorites_count: coalesce(f.count, 0)},
  select_merge: %{downloads_count: coalesce(d.count, 0)},
  order_by: ^sort,
  group_by: w.id)
```

In addition I want to sort on count fields (`favorites_count` & `downloads_count`). Put this part static in query will work.

```
...
order_by: coalesce(d.count, 0),
```

---

My question now is how to handle this like the first example with dynamic variable. I didn't find a way to handle this.

```
sort = [asc: :favorites_count, asc: :name] # comes from request
...
order_by: ^sort,
```

Ends up with `Unknown column 'w0.favorites_count' in 'order clause'`

```
order_by: ^foo(sort),

def foo(sort), do: coalesce(:count, 0)
```

Ends up with `undefined function coalesce/2 (fragment/3)`

Using `dynamic/2` ends up with `expected a field as an atom, a list or keyword list in 'order_by', got: 'dynamic(...)'`

I understand the main problem, but didn't get a solution. Any ideas or in best case solutions? Thanks for help!

Comment: can you share `favorites_count_query`, my understanding is you should use fragment and use `as` to alias the fields in subquery

Comment: this will work for dynamic fields https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#field/2

Comment: @ZubairNabi I add the subquery for favorites. Does this help, have you some example with fragment use?

Comment: @script That didn't work for dynamical build the order by part. I can't use them outside of query which I need to decide if the first parameter is `w`, `f` or `d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is call [order_by/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#order_by/3) as function multiple times instead of generate list and put them directly in [from/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#from/2).

```
sort = [asc: :favorites_count, asc: :name] # comes from request

from(w in Wallpaper, ...)
|> order_wallpapers(sort)

...

defp order_wallpapers(query, []), do: query

defp order_wallpapers(query, [{order, :favorites_count} = sort|others]) do
  query
  |> order_by([w, f, d], [{^order, f.count}])
  |> order_wallpapers(others)
end

defp order_wallpapers(query, [sort|others]) do
  query
  |> order_by([w, f, d], ^[sort])
  |> order_wallpapers(others)
end
```

Comment: can you post the full query? I'm so confused.

Comment: The dotted out part in `from(w in Wallpaper, ...)` is the same as in the question only without `order_by` key.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to do this much simpler so here's my solution:

```
from(p in Post,
  order_by: [desc_nulls_last: fragment("array_length(?, 1)", p.votes)]
)
|> Repo.all()
```

The `desc_nulls_last` you can choose yourself, but the fragment works very well. `array_length` is a PostgreSQL specific thing so watch out for that!

Comment: Your example is much simpler but doesn't give a correct answer to my problem. Your code shows a static sort of data. I want to keep sorting dynamically and would decide with parameters (`sort = [asc: :favorites_count, asc: :name]`) which fields should sorted.